# jQuery - Only Targetting First Element with Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a carousel - A personal project to help me learn jQuery, a little more fun than just reading!

I've hit a bit of a bump - I'm trying to target all of my ".item"'s but it's just hitting the first one and stopping.  From what I've seen I need to use an Array?  And I've tried but it's still only targeting the first one.

Here's a Fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/baxjf3bz/

And I think the issue is with this bit of code:

```
item.each(function(i){

            itemNo [i] = item;
            item.css("left", carouselItemNo * carouselItemWidth - 192 + "px");

        });
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

jQuery targets the item.  It grabs the rel and multiply's by the width and then minuses the width so it's in the right place.  So each item will be exactly 192px left of the previous one.  So they're all visible.  If that makes sense?

Any help and explanation of where I'm going wrong would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to use the array for, but you can set the left property of each item in your collection by using a function when setting the css property.

http://jsfiddle.net/baxjf3bz/1/

```
item.css('left', function(i){
    var offset = ( i * carouselItemWidth );
    return offset;
});
```

This will set the 'left' property for each item in your collection, the variable `i` is the index of the current item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to increment with `i` This is the actual element currently being looped over, not the index of the selected elements.